# How to convert decimal quantity to a fractional quantity using sin(x)?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm embarrassed to say I never properly learned how to do this, but in my Calc Physics class I need to find the hypotenuse of an angle give the $sin(40)$ or $.642788$ using only 3 significant figures.

I get a decimal answer and I don't know how to put it in fractional form so that I can derive the hypotenuse.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to determine the hypotenuse, you need more than an angle: If you have an angle $40^\circ$, then $$\sin(40^\circ) = \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}} \iff \text{hypotenuse }= \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\sin(40^\circ)}$$

where "opposite" refers to the length of the of the leg of the right triangle opposite the angle measuring $40^\circ$.  So, without knowing the length of this *opposite* leg, there is no way of calculating the length of the hypotenuse given only $\sin(40^\circ)$.

What you *do* know is that the *ratio* of the length of the opposite leg with respect to the length of the hypotenuse is equal to $$\sin(40^\circ) \approx \dfrac{.642788}1\text{ or }\dfrac{64.2788}{100}$$

Comment: You're right she gave us 1.0m for the opposite leg.

Comment: Good! You're good to go, then!